# open side panel on page onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, panels

I want to open a side panel on page onload

code fragment used is

```
$(document).ready(function(event,ui)
{
   $("#mypanel").panel("open",{display: 'overlay', position: 'left'});
});
```

Comment: please tell me why this is not workig??

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on jquery mobile but in this example([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/F28aj/)) the Panel is open on document load

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mypanel").panel("open");
})
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">          
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-theme="a" class="ui-response">
        <p>This is my content</p>
    </div>
   <div data-role="content">
     <a href="#mypanel" data-role="button" data-display="overlay" data-position="left" data-dismissible="true">Panel open/close</a>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.

Comment: Hey everything seems perfect here, I want to ask a quicky here that in the <a> tag data-rel markup is not required..??

Comment: and yes http://jsfiddle.net/F28aj/1/ see adding lots of text to the body of the page but when the panel opens on the left the text shits to the right side despite mentioning class="ui-responsive"